# Duplicate error messaging for require_from_group

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use the jQuery Validate plugin to group two fields and have one error message for the group.

I have two fields (grouped) and if both of them aren't filled out, I would like to display a single error message stating `You must either fill out 'U.S. taxpayer identification number' or 'Foreign tax identifying number'`. Right now, the form is creating SIX separate error messages that simply state `Please fill at least 1 of these fields.`

I've included my code below:

**the html**:

```
<input class="tin" name="w8_us_tin" type="text" style="width: 50.8%; height: 1.8%; top: 42.1%; left: 10.3%;">
<input class="tin" name="w8_foreign_tin" type="text" style="width: 30%; height: 1.8%; top: 42.1%; left: 64.2%;">
```

**the javascript**:

```
$(function () {
    $("form.signup_3").validate({
        errorElement: "li",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo( $("ul.error") );
        },
        groups: {
            tin: "w8_us_tin w8_foreign_tin"
        },
        rules: {
            w8_us_tin:{
                require_from_group: [1, '.tin']
            },
            w8_foreign_tin:{
                require_from_group: [1, '.tin']
            }
        },
        messages: {
            tin: {
                require_from_group: "You must either fill out 'U.S. taxpayer identification number' or 'Foreign tax identifying number'"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I just realized your description does not really match your code.  How can you possibly be getting six identical messages when your code is only showing TWO fields?  Please show enough code to properly reproduce the issue.  Otherwise, it's working:  http://jsfiddle.net/7LsHJ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the `groups` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#groups).

> "A group consists of an arbitrary group name as the key and a space separated list of element names as the value. Use `errorPlacement` to control where the group message is placed."

It's sole purpose is to take the error messages from several fields and turn them into one message.  Maybe messy for fields with different rules that trigger at different times.  However, it's perfect in your case when any of the grouped fields get the same message at the same time, such as when triggered by the `require_from_group` method.

```
groups: {
    someArbitraryName: "w8_us_tin w8_foreign_tin"
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/7LsHJ/**

---

**Quote OP:**

> "Right now, the form is creating SIX separate error messages that simply state `Please fill at least 1 of these fields`."

I have no idea how you can be getting six messages when you only have two fields, but I know exactly why you're seeing the generic `Please fill at least x` message.

You cannot have an item called `tin` within `messages` since it's not a field `name`.

```
messages: {
    tin: {  // <- this is not a field name
        require_from_group: "You must either fill out 'U.S. taxpayer identification number' or 'Foreign tax identifying number'"
    }     
}
```

The `messages` are assigned in a similar fashion as the `rules`.  Each item within the `messages` option is *always* assigned to a field `name`.

One message for all rules on a field:

```
messages: {
    fieldName: "custom message same for all rules on this field"
}
```

OR a custom message for each rule on a field:

```
messages: {
    fieldName: {
        required: "custom message for required rule",
        digits: "custom message for digits rule"
    }
}
```

Applied to your case:

```
messages: {
    w8_us_tin: {
        require_from_group: "You must either fill out 'U.S. taxpayer identification number' or 'Foreign tax identifying number'"
    },
    w8_foreign_tin: {
        require_from_group: "You must either fill out 'U.S. taxpayer identification number' or 'Foreign tax identifying number'"
    }
}
```

**Updated DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/7LsHJ/1/**

Comment: Thanks for the help, Sparky. The duplicate messages bug was fixed by using errorLabelContainer instead of errorPlacement.

Comment: @585connor, I initially missed the `appendTo` in your code.  The `errorPlacement` and `errorLabelContainer` callbacks do two different things and you shouldn't need any form of `append` in either one.  No matter how/where you place the messages, the plugin automatically toggles them, so using an `append` typically causes duplication.